# Creating a new Tomcat Project

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I want to create easily a Tomcat Project in eclipse. This means that I want file tab then new tab then Tomcat Project tab. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the web tools into Eclipse, and then you'll be able to create a new web application project and then target it to a Tomcat server.